# Protocols in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to create a FileManager using protocols in Swift.

It is simply a struct

```
struct AppFile: AppFileManipulation {

    let fileName: String

    init(fileName: String)
    {
        self.fileName = fileName
    }

}
```

which is created in the code

```
let file = AppFile(fileName: "testfile.txt")
```

now I want to separate out different functions into different protocols

One of these gives the status for the file, here it is with file exists

```
protocol AppFileStatus
{
    func exists(file at: URL) -> Bool
}

extension AppFileStatus
{
    func exists(file at: URL) -> Bool
    {
        return FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: at.path)
    }
}
```

and I want to have a separate protocol that has file operations

```
protocol AppFileManipulation : AppDirectoryNames, AppFileStatus
{
    func writeStringsToFile(containing: String, to path: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory, withName name: String) -> Bool
}

extension AppFileManipulation
{
        func writeStringsToFile(containing: String, to path: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory, withName name: String) -> Bool{

}
    }
```

Now for various reasons (to check if the file already exists, actually) I want the body of writeStringsToFile to access exists(file at: URL).

One solution would be to put everything into the same protocol, but really I wanted to split the functionality out. Another option would be to repeat code.

How should I structure this so I can access the AppFileStatus methods from within the AppFileManipulation protocol?

Here is a sample project; https://github.com/stevencurtis/ProtocolFileHandling

Comment: You generally don't need an initializer for a struct.

Comment: The sentence would be "Generally you don't", but generally is also not the right word in this sentence.

Comment: Why do you need the protocols in the first place?

Comment: A protocol defines a blueprint of methods, properties, and other requirements that suit a particular task or piece of functionality. This makes Protocol oriented programming quite popular these days. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267

Comment: If you want to do this then your method writeStringsToFile should take a parameter of type AppFileStatus , that is a class/struct that conforms to this protocol. But this doesn't really make sense which makes me question the usability of AppFileStatus. Also, your AppFile struct shouldn't have a fileName proeprty but rather a URL property like fileUrl IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the where Self option for your extension:

```
struct AppFile: AppFileStatus, AppFileManipulation {

    let fileName: String

    init(fileName: String)
    {
        self.fileName = fileName
    }
}


protocol AppFileStatus
{
    func exists(file at: URL) -> Bool
}


extension AppFileStatus
{
    func exists(file at: URL) -> Bool
    {
        return FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: at.path)
    }
}


protocol AppFileManipulation
{
    func writeStringsToFile(containing: String, to path: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory, withName name: String) -> Bool
}


extension AppFileManipulation where Self: AppFileStatus
{
    func writeStringsToFile(containing: String, to path: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory, withName name: String) -> Bool{
            let exists = self.exists(file: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))

            return true
    }
}
```

and now you can call:

```
let file = AppFile(fileName: "testfile.txt")
file.writeStringsToFile(containing: ..., to: ..., withName: ...)
```